# LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

This code is working fine and I would like for it to be reviewed. Am I using extra objects and variables to store values?

**`LinkedList`**

```
package lab5;

public class LinkedList {

    public static void main(String argsp[]) {
        List ob = new List();

        ob.addAtStart("y", 6);
        ob.addAtStart("w", 4);
        ob.addAtStart("z", 3);

        ob.addAtEnd("a", 3);
        ob.addAtEnd("b", 4);
        ob.addAtEnd("c", 5);

        /*
         * ob.display(); System.out.println("Deleted first one");
         * ob.deleteFromStart();
         */
        ob.display();
        System.out.println("Deleted End one");
        ob.deleteFromEnd();
        ob.display();
    }
}
```

**`List`**

```
package lab5;

public class List {

    Node head;

    public List() {
        head = null;
    }

    public List(Node e) {
        head = e;
    }

    Node oldfirst = null;
    Node lasthead = null;

    public void addAtStart(String name, int age) {
        Node newObject = new Node(name, age);
        newObject.next = head;

        if (oldfirst == null) {
            oldfirst = newObject;
        }
        head = newObject;
        lasthead = head;

    }

    public void display() {
        Node store = head;
        while (store != null) {
            store.display();
            store = store.next;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void addAtEnd(String name, int age) {
        Node atEndValue = new Node(name, age);
        oldfirst.next = atEndValue;
        oldfirst = atEndValue;
    }

    public void deleteFromStart() {
        if (head.next != null) {
            head = head.next;
        }
    }

    public void deleteFromEnd() {
        Node start = head;
        Node prev = null;
        while (head != null) {
            prev = head;
            head = head.next;
        }
        prev.next = null;
        head = prev;
    }

    public Node search(String name) {
        return head;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return (head.toString()).length();
    }
}
```

**`Node`**

```
package lab5;

public class Node {

    String name;
    int age;
    Node next;

    public Node() {
        name = "Abc";
        age = 10;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        next = null;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + " Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post seems fine here, but it's not clear what you're actually asking? What is your question? Please read our [on-topic](/help/on-topic) and [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) pages.

Comment: I was told by few people your code need review. Am I using extra objects and variable to store values?

Comment: We get many [tag:linked-list] questions here. It would help if you included some context about what this code is expected to accomplish. If it's a [tag:homework] question, then you should include the instructions too.

Comment: Yes this is homework task.

Comment: Can I ask why I get -1 ?

Comment: @BadarShahzadKhan You got a -1 (Not from me) because you just posted code and said. Review.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't leave code lying about**

When you're done with code, delete it, don't just comment it out.  It adds unnecessary noise to your code and makes it look messy.

**Unused code / Construction from Node**

You don't currently seem to use this constructor:

```
public List(Node e) {
    head = e;
}
```

How likely are you to use it?  What's going to have constructed the `Node` / `Node` chain that you're assigning into your list.  If it's not needed get rid of it.  If it is needed, then consider if you really want the `Node` to be shared between the list and it's caller.

**oldfirst / bug**

This is a very odd variable name at a class level.  It sounds like something you might use as a temporary variable in a method, for example when removing/replacing the head of the list.  It's usage is also rather odd.  For example in `addAtStart` you do:

```
if (oldfirst == null) {
    oldfirst = newObject;
}
```

So, you only assign to it the first time you add an item?!?

This also seems to result in a bug, where if you `addAtEnd` before you've `addAtStart`, you will do:

```
Node atEndValue = new Node(name, age);
oldfirst.next = atEndValue;
oldfirst = atEndValue;
```

Until you call `addAtStart`, `oldfirst` is null, so `oldfirst.next` is going to crash...

**Naming**

Think about what variables you're declaring at a class level and what their purpose is, then give them names that reflect that.  It will be a lot easier to follow your code and identify bugs.  In this instance, it seems like perhaps `oldfirst` is actually supposed to pointing at the tail/end of the list, rather than the head.

Consider what you're supposed to do to any class variables (such as `oldfirst`) when you delete items from the list.

Comment: Thank you! you give me time and response to my code. Inshallah! I will in future code to abstain these faults. Moreover, I accept I have bad smell in my code that's why I recommend by someone to post here. I learnt 3 things today from you. Thank you ! @forsvarir